# I'd like to send some keys by SendInput API

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I want to send some keys to a game by SendInput API on C#. (My environment is Windows 7 64bit)

I wrote some codes as follows:

```
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   static extern int SendInput(int nInputs, INPUT[] pInputs, int cbSize);       

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        public int dx;
        public int dy;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        public short wVk;
        public short wScan;
        public int dwFlags;
        public int time;            
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        public uint uMsg;
        public ushort wParamL;
        public ushort wParamH;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private struct INPUT
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public uint type;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public MOUSEINPUT mi;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public KEYBDINPUT ki;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
    }        

    public static void WalkFront()
    {
        INPUT[] inputs = new INPUT[1];

        Keys virtualKeycode = (Keys)0x15;            

        inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;            
        inputs[0].ki.wVk = (short)virtualKeycode;
        inputs[0].ki.wScan = (short)MapVirtualKey((int)virtualKeycode, 0);            
        inputs[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;            
        inputs[0].ki.time = 0;
        inputs[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();

        SendInput(1, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(inputs[0]));        
    }
```

However it does not work correctly.

Apparently, this code can send **BackSpace** to the game. In fact, this code can delete a character on Notepad.exe.

Bizarrely, this code only sends **BackSpace** to the applications. I changed the keycode (I tried 0x14, 0x13, 0x12...etc) in this code. **However, this code only sends BackSpace**

I want to send another key (J, K, L...etc) to applications but I could not.

Any advices?
Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `inputs[0].ki.wScan` before the `SendInput` call is made? Is the `MapVirtualKey` function succeeding, or returning 0?

Comment: You are mixing up virtual keys and scan codes.  Virtual key 0x15 is only available on Japanese keyboards.  0x15 is however the scan code for the backspace key.  Do consider using the .NET SendKeys class.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I try to .NET SendKeys class however, I can not send keys to a game. Probability, the game use DirectInput so I think that I have to use low-level API such as SendInputs.

Comment: MapVirtualKey function is returning 0

Comment: This is why it's important to check return values. If `MapVirtualKey` is returning 0, then that means there's no translation from the virtual key code that you're passing it to a scan code. This is clear from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306.aspx), specifically the "Return value" section. Since that function isn't working, your call to `SendInput` isn't working.

Comment: But I agree with Hans's suggestion: use `SendKeys`. As long as you're running Windows Vista or later, it's going to use `SendInput` under the hood (it uses a journal hook on previous versions of Windows, but that breaks with UAC). You can force that behavior on all versions of Windows by modifying your `app.config` file. This is explained in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx). Since `SendKeys` didn't work for your purposes, and it uses `SendInput`, it's unlikely that `SendInput` will work even once you get it working.

Comment: Do consider Stefan's answer—a keyboard event consists of a key-down and key-up message in sequence. You need to send both, otherwise the other application will probably ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that a keypress event consists of a key-down and after that a key-up event. That means to "send a backspace" you need to call SendInput twice, once with the key pressed, once with the key released.
If you fail to call SendInput with the key released, subsequent key presses will most likely be ignored by most apps.